# JScrollPane mouse-wheel area

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, mousewheel

I have a `JScrollPane` and a `JPanel` inside. I see the scrollbars when needed, but the mouse wheeling works only when the mouse is over the scrollbars. Is there a property or something to make mouse wheeling work when the mouse pointer is over the whole panel, not just the scrollbars? You know like in browsers - you can scroll the page even if the mouse pointer is not over the scrollbars.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me (Java 6, Windows, JScrollPane containing a JPanel, mouse wheeling over JPanel). JPanel with rounded 100 pixel borders, min size 1000x1000, preferred size (4000x4000).

So I guess, that your existing code interferes. Try a separate example, and then rework your app.

Comment: I had a `MouseWheelMoved` listener. When I removed it, everything worked fine. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure main window(possibly a `JFrame`) implements `Scrollable`.

Comment: @mKorbel - I am now confused if this is a standard functionality of JScrollPane. Why should I implement `Scrollable`? `Joop Eggen` says it is a standard one. I will look again at my code.

Comment: @Petar Minchev that's right, remove all MouseWheel & NouseMotionListeners at first