# Autoscroll not working when used scrollwheel

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, caret

I am working on a little Swing application and I want to disable all possible scrolling in a scrollpane but autoscroll. The code i have is below:

```
private void removeScrollBar(JScrollPane scrollPane){
    scrollPane.setBounds(10, 35, 250, 525);
    scrollPane.setBackground(new Color(1, 0, 0, 0));
    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
    scrollPane.getViewport().setBorder(null);
    scrollPane.setViewportBorder(null);
    scrollPane.setBorder(null);
    scrollPane.setWheelScrollingEnabled(false);
}
```

Basically when I scroll while the cursor is above the scrollPane, it disables the autoscrolling, which is handled by a JTextArea Caret. The code for that is below:

```
((DefaultCaret) textArea.getCaret()).setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have a look at [Why JScrollPane does not react to mouse wheel events?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911506/why-jscrollpane-does-not-react-to-mouse-wheel-events).

Comment: It sounds like you're putting a lot of effort into making your application hard to use. Why work so hard to change the scrolling mechanism that they're used to?

Comment: @bill haha:) yess, It is to make it easier for myself, I basically have 3 scrollpanes that need to be scrolled in sync, I'm doing that automatically, but now i decided to use a simple synchronizer class that transfers the value from 1 scrollbar to the other. get it? probably not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically when I scroll while the cursor is above the scrollPane, it disables the autoscrolling, which is handled by a JTextArea Caret.

Not sure, but maybe you can use [Smart Scrolling](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/03/03/smart-scrolling/).

It disables automatic scrolling when the scrollbar is not at the bottom of the scroll pane.