# Horizontal Scrolling Listener

Tags: java, horizontal-scrolling

I feel like I have searched half the Web and found no solution...
I have a java application displaying a Map(different countries etc.).
 currently you are able to scroll down and up using your mouse wheel...
I want it so, that you are able to scroll sideways (horizontally). 
All I need is a Listener (in Swing or Javafx does not matter) triggering whenever the mousewheel gets tilted, without the need for a focus of the map (hovering with your mouse should be enough the windows should still be focused) and without any visible scrollbars.

Comment: What about '' node.setOnScroll(new EventHandler()...''?  It gives Y and X coordinates.

Comment: It does not trigger on sideway scrolling...

Comment: Had a similar problem once. This was the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911506/why-jscrollpane-does-not-react-to-mouse-wheel-events

JScrollPane did not react to mouse wheel scrolls.

Comment: My problem is, that the event is triggering on normal scroll events, but is not recognizing sideway scrolling as well sideway scrolling...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following code every time you scroll sideways a message gets printed out...

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            scene.setOnScroll(new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>(){

                @Override
                public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("Scroll:" + event.getDeltaX());
                }
            });
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

One thing to consider:
Apparently when embedding a JFXPanel into a JFrame the sideway scrolling event is not getting passed.