# How disable mouse wheel scroll on all component except parent

Tags: java, swing

I have a `jFrame` along with `jScrollPane` in this `jScrollPane` there are few other component such as `jTextField` `jTextArea` `jTable` etc.. (this form I have designed with NetBeans form designer)

`jScrollPane` (the Parent Component) has vertical scroll bar and it scroll with the mouse wheel. But when mouse move on a `jTextArea` or a `jTable` (they have there own scroll bars)  Mouse Wheel focus goes to them and scrolling them instead of scrolling `jScrollPane`. I want to keep scroll focus on `jScrollPane` without going it to any other component in it.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[found a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911506/why-jscrollpane-does-not-react-to-mouse-wheel-events?rq=1)

```
scrollPane = new JScrollPane() {

    @Override
    protected void processMouseWheelEvent(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        if (!isWheelScrollingEnabled()) {
            if (getParent() != null) 
                getParent().dispatchEvent(
                        SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent(this, e, getParent()));
            return;
        }
        super.processMouseWheelEvent(e);
    }

};
scrollPane.setWheelScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: this still doesnt work for me, I have the exact same problem, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I did this in my panel and it worked...

```
 jScrollPane1.removeMouseWheelListener(jScrollPane1.getMouseWheelListeners()[0]);
```